# Unable to port forward via ssh on windows

Tags: windows, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to port forward from a windows machine to a linux box.
In doing so, I want to create an ssh tunnel that runs in the background. According to the ssh [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh) this is done with the `-f` parameter in order to put the tunnel in the background as well as the `-N` parameter to indicate to not execute any command.

`ssh -L <port>:<host>:<port> user@remote_ip -i ~/path/to/id/file` executes perfectly fine.
Running: `ssh -L <port>:<host>:<port> user@remote_ip -i ~/path/to/id/file -f -N -vvv`(Note the `-f`, `-N`)
Results in some documentation finally landing on: `debug1: forking to background`
Where it just hangs without ever going to the background or giving me access to the remote server.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

For reference I am trying to connect a python script to a remote postgres database and this is my first time working within the Windows environment - I have the same script on a Mac which runs fine. The machine I am working on is on Windows 10 with the OpenSSH client installed.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so had same issue, some digging later:

https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/999

Problem seems to be unable to fork existing console, if you need in a script, then start another console using either "start ssh" or start-process from powershell